# Some conditions on self-adjoint operator.

Tags: operator-theory

I have a bounded, invertible and positive operator on an $N-$dimensional Hilbert space $V$. I want prove or disprove that it is also self-adjoint.

I would like to read an answer with some approaches to be followed for this purpose.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is true over complex Hilbert spaces, but not real Hilbert spaces

Comment: Also, every operator on an $N$-dimensional space is bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking at a real (as opposed to complex) Hilbert space, then it depends on what you mean by positive.

Note, for example, that if we take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
then we have $\langle x, Ax \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you. However, for the real case, what can I do to show that an operator is self-adjoit?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I showed you that in the real case, the operator is **not** necessarily self-adjoint

Comment: $A$, in particular, is not self-adjoint

Comment: Excuse me, I explained badly. What I want to know is: in general, for bounded, invertible and positive operator on the real Hilbert space, what can I do to show that an operator is self-adjoit?

Comment: And as I have shown you, there is nothing you can do, because this statement isn't true.  To show you that this is not true, I have given you an example of a bounded, invertible, and positive operator that is **not** self adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

**This is true for complex Hilbert spaces (added after valuable comments!).**

If $T$ is a positive operator you have by definition $\langle Tx, x \rangle \ge 0$ for all vector $x$ in the considered space $E$. Hence $\langle Tx, x \rangle$ is real for all $x \in E$ which implies that $T$ is self-adjoint in the complex case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, is positivity sufficient to prove that operator is self-adjoint?

Comment: @Mark. Yes and you have the proof in my answer.

Comment: This is true over complex Hilbert spaces, but not real Hilbert spaces

Comment: Take for instance the matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$...